# How to increase crew member damage and armor?

Tags: starbound

Sometimes colonists and surrendered enemies ask to become crew members on your ship. I found them to be quite useful as they <del>act as meat shields</del> help engage enemies in combat. However, I'd like to outfit them with better/different weapons and armor. Is there any way I can upgrade their weapon or armor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently as of 1.0 stable there is no way to change the crew's weaponry or armor. Instead, their armor and damage scale as you progress through the game.

**Note:** As of version 1.0.2, crew damage will be normal when you recruit them, but as soon as you beam up to your ship and back down again, their damage falls off really strongly (see [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/starbound/comments/4uyyg7/just_in_case_anyone_wasnt_convinced_heres/) for details). **This is a bug, and has been fixed in 1.0.3.**

Comment: Post only mentions damage though. But let's hope this is indeed a bug, because right now the crew can't even cannon fodder properly for me

Comment: Honestly, their AI is so wonky that even if their damage was buffed, I'd still prefer to venture out solo. At least that way I don't have to worry about them jumping into a spike pit.

Comment: The 1.0.3 Patch just arrived, and according to patch note they changed something:

 `change power scaling of crew members to more closely match the power scaling of the player`